# How to view your in production VueJS project locally before publish changes

Tags: vue.js, local, netlify, production, web-development-server

I have VueJS project published on Netlify, what i want to do is to make modifications to this project and see my changes locally before i update the repo on GitHub and publish the changes on Netlify. So simply i'm trying to find a way to serve the project locally but this doesn't work anymore after the project got published on Netlify.

Whenever i run npm run serve i get the below error:

```
PS F:\Projects\reaction-timer-testing> npm run serve
> reaction-timer-testing@0.1.0 serve
> vue-cli-service serve
'vue-cli-service' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I assume this is because that project is in build mode and i did that by running npm run build while i was publishing it to Netlify.

I've read someone recommends to run serve -s dist and this got me no where because each time i visit the local link `http://localhost:3000` it gets `404: the requested path could not be found`.

Another one advised to download and install xampp but i don't know what to do next i think i've tried everything.

Here is a view of my project files (it's a very simple project that i made for learning)

[Pic of project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV7LJ.png)

Link to the project on Netlify: https://reaction-timer-testing.netlify.app/